# Vertical centering with transform not working as expected

Tags: html, css

Usually this code works, but for some reason it's not vertically centering within it's parent element. Could this be because of the background image?

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/BcmNw/

```
<div class="background-image">
    <div class="omg-title">This is the title</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background-image {
    background-image: url('');
    height: 600px;
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.omg-title {
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Its because of `position:absolute` .. why you need that?

Comment: I've just removed that and it makes no difference

Comment: I am checking in Mozilla and its perfect after removing position:absolute. whats your browser?

Comment: It works for you @Era because he's only using the `-webkit-` prefix for `transform`. If you add the `-moz-` prefix, it will be weird for you too :)

Comment: in google chrome `-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` is affecting... now y u need this?

Comment: If he wants it centered, `.background-image` already does that with `text-align:center;`... No idea why he needs styles for `.omg-title` at all...

Comment: Sorry, vertically centered. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using position: absolute you can remove transform and set the text to center with the following changes:

```
.omg-title {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

To perfect center horizontally you should know the width of the text, for example if it's 100px you should apply `margin-left: -50px;`

An example of the second solution http://jsfiddle.net/7ScDh/

Comment: Silly mistake, top:50%; and left: 50% fixed the transform center. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these, or remove absolute positioning:

1) center .omg-title div

```
.omg-title {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -50px; // depending on width
}
```

2) give .omg-title div full width:

```
.omg-title {
    width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: For vertical allignment, try (demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/6E5as/):

```
.omg-title {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -10px; // depending on height
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just take away all of `.omg-title`'s styling, it centers fine because `.background-image` has `text-align:center;`.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/PrYw3/) for proof

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position and transform property and it will work for you:

```
.omg-title {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry — I meant vertically aligned with transform.